Updating Search Params without causing page re-render
I have a page with a very heavy render time, maybe 1s total. On this page, I have an accordion that is a custom component (using React 18). Clicking it reveals a dropdown of other accordions, eventually leading to a link. This is our support page.
My main problem here is search parameters. I was initially handling the "active" state via a custom useState hook and performance was fine, as updating it would only re-render itself and the children. However, I am required to add the active categories to the URL.
I am using a Tanstack router that has a navigate() function and am able to add the state easily. I have then moved the state to grab the categories from the URL to determine whether it is active or not. This causes a full page re-render, which causes about 1 second of lag between me clicking the dropdown and its laggily opening. This lag is only present when I handle the state through the URL params.
Any ideas on how I can make this more performant while keeping the state and URL in sync?
    function toggleActive() {
        navigate({
            search: (prev) => {
                if (!prev.categories) return { categories: category.slug };
                const categories = prev.categories.split(',');
                if (categories.includes(category.slug)) {
                    return {
                        categories: categories
                            .filter((urlCategory) => urlCategory !== category.slug)
                            .filter((urlCategory) => !allChildSlugs.includes(urlCategory))
                            .join(',')
                    };
                } else {
                    categories.push(category.slug);
                    return { categories: categories.join(',') };
                }
            }
        });
    }


This usually occurs for me in both React and in NextJs as well and according to my observation this routing change usually takes longer in dev environment try building the react app and running the build it shouldn't take much time compared to before

Unfortunately this is not a dev environment issue. I've already built it, but testing without the URL params its so much faster
